# Recursive stored procedure in HSQLDB

Tags: recursion, stored-procedures, hsqldb

is it possible to create recursive stored procedure in HSQLDB ?

I wrote the following one to update a record and recursively all the parent records:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateFolderTotals(IN p_id VARCHAR(32), IN p_size BIGINT, IN p_files INT, IN p_folders INT) 
  MODIFIES SQL DATA 
  BEGIN ATOMIC  
    DECLARE l_parentid VARCHAR(32); 
    UPDATE folders  
    SET tot_files = tot_files + p_files, 
        tot_size = tot_size + p_size , 
        tot_folders = tot_folders + p_folders 
    WHERE id = p_id;  

    SELECT parentid INTO l_parentid FROM folders WHERE id = p_id; 

    IF (l_parentid IS NOT NULL) THEN 
        CALL updateFolderTotals(l_parentid,p_size,p_files,p_folders); 
    END IF; 

  END;
```

but I get the following error:

`user lacks privilege or object not found: UPDATEFOLDERTOTALS / Error Code: -5501 / State: 42501`

In HyperSQL User Guide I've found some info (see [Recursive Routines](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_recursive_routines) in HyperSQL User Guide) but it seems it is supported for funtions only.

Thank you in advance for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create recursive procedures following the same guidelines. First create the procedure with a simple body that throws an exception. You need to specify the SPECIFIC name of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateFolderTotals(IN p_id VARCHAR(32), IN p_size BIGINT, IN p_files   INT, IN p_folders INT) 
  SPECIFIC updateFolderTotals_1 MODIFIES SQL DATA 
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
```

Then alter the created procedure with the full body:

```
ALTER SPECIFIC ROUTINE updateFolderTotals_1
  BEGIN ATOMIC  
  DECLARE l_parentid VARCHAR(32); 
  UPDATE folders  
  SET tot_files = tot_files + p_files, 
    tot_size = tot_size + p_size , 
    tot_folders = tot_folders + p_folders 
  WHERE id = p_id;  

  SELECT parentid INTO l_parentid FROM folders WHERE id = p_id; 

  IF (l_parentid IS NOT NULL) THEN 
    CALL updateFolderTotals(l_parentid,p_size,p_files,p_folders); 
  END IF; 
END;
```